# how to get different elements with same class name using xpath scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get elements of particular class but it has many elements like `p`,`pre`,`code`,`span` and I want all of them in sequential order as they are inside the class.

Here is how structure looks like: (I want to get all elements of `div class = "s-prose js-post-body"`)
[image]

or

[image]

There may different types of elements inside this `div class` and i want all in same sequence as they seems.
I am getting hard time figuring out xpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements with `s-prose` and `js-post-body` as class names, you could use the following line, which will store the elements in a list.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='s-prose js-post-body']")
```

Comment: it is one class name not 2 different like `@class= s-prose js-post-body`

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Updated it now.

Comment: sorry it doesn't help...this doesn't solve nested elements and they are returned along

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are looking for. You want each element within the div stored in a list or something? Do you want the html code or the text?

Comment: I want the text of each element, it might be nested element in some case but there might not be in others.